# Adding OpenMP support to compiler command line

Tags: command-line, compiler

When I am giving this command `make -j4` I am getting this

```
mlpack was compiled with OpenMP support, but you are compiling without OpenMP support.  
This will almost certainly cause irreparable disaster.  Either enable OpenMP support in your 
application (e.g.,add -fopenmp to your compiler command line), or, recompile mlpack *without* 
OpenMP support.
```

I am doing this on my ubuntu terminal.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

I am trying to build [MLPack Model Zoo](https://github.com/mlpack/models). I was done with main MLPack library but was stuck with this [ModelZoo](https://github.com/mlpack/models) part.

Comment: Can you give some more contect? what software are you trying to build, where did you obtain the source code, and how did you configure the build?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mlpack is installed with OpenMP support, and you are trying to install MLPack Model Zoo without OpenMP support. Perhaps a bug in the makefile. Find the corresponding line in the makefile and add the OpenMP compiler flag (f.i. -fopenmp) where applicable.